# How to use moveFile react-native-fs

Tags: react-native, filesystems, react-native-fs, movefile

i need share local image on react native app, use react-native share and react-native-fs. Image is in local folder in root app named 'images'. How to share this image. Do i need copy or move image to temp and use that image for getting absolute path.

This is my code. rnfs.movefile don't work

```
getAssetFileAbsolutePath = async () => {
  const dest =
  `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}${Math.random().toString(36)
   .substring( 
    .7)}.png`;
  const img = './images/page1.png';
  try {
    await RNFS.moveFile(img, dest);
    console.log("dobro", dest)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("greska", err)
  } 
 }
```

I get error “page1.png” couldn’t be moved to “tmp” because either the former doesn’t exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn’t exist.

Answer (score -1):

use [rn-fetch blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) with react native share 
first find path of the image  and convert it to base64.
then share image use react native share package

```
ShareFile(file) {
    let imagePath = null;
    RNFetchBlob.config({
        fileCache: true
    })
    .fetch("GET", file)
    // the image is now dowloaded to device's storage
    .then(resp => {
        // the image path you can use it directly with Image component
        imagePath = resp.path();
        return resp.readFile("base64");
    })
    .then(async base64Data => {
        var base64Data = `data:image/png;base64,` + base64Data;
        // here's base64 encoded image
        await Share.open({ url: base64Data });
        // remove the file from storage
        return fs.unlink(imagePath);
    });
}
```

Comment: is file string like './images/page1.png'?

Comment: have error Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):
Error: unsupported URL

Comment: in case  .fetch("GET", file) file must be API?